# React Native Branch.io Share Sheet parameters

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-navigation, branch.io

I've implemented branch.io in my react native project.
I'm having troubles finding out how to include custom parameters in the showShareSheet function.
My goal is to use them to navigate to the correct screen.
I'm using React Navigation.

```
this._branchUniversalObj.showShareSheet({
  // Include custom info here?
  shareOptions: {
    messageHeader: 'Title',
    messageBody: 'My message body',
    emailSubject: 'My email subject'
  },
  linkProperties: {
    feature: 'spot-share'
  }
}).then(({ channel, completed, error }) => {

});
```

Comment: Amruta from Branch here. Unfortunately, you will not be able to add custom parameters to the link, based on the channel selected. Our engineers are looking into this. They will roll out a new version of the Android/iOS SDK (The react native SDK uses the native Android/iOS SDK) with this feature, where you can add custom parameters to the link based on the channel selected.